# Google Spreadsheet - CONCATENATE with a twist Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet where I want to add a " - " if there is a subtitle. If there is not a Subtitle, I want to leave it out. On a technical note: Both columns contains text only and can be any text as well.

[image: Screenshot Google Sheet]

My current formula is like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(B87; " - ";C87)
```

I've been looking and trying formula's, but none working so far. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you kindly in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete range A87:A and use in A87:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C87:C=""; B87:B; B87:B&" - "&C87:C))
```

Comment: Thnx for taking a llook! However, I got an error message: #REF!, "The array result is not comprehensive because it overwrites data in A88."

Comment: @Jonathan its arrayformula which means it will auto-populate range A87:A. arrayformula needs a space for to roll out the output therefore range A87:A needs to be empty. so again... as  mentioned in answer: "delete range A87:A and use in A87"

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested but it doesn't seems to work I'm sorry. I'm not an expert in this field. I deleted the cell on the first column, added the code and it's giving me this error. What do you mean with 'needs a space for to roll out the output'? I did empty it, so I don't get it.

Comment: @Jonathan can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I got it working took me a while to understand it haha. Thank you very much! I misunderstood the word 'array'. I did not know that was possible, so I copy pasted the code on every first column of the row.